# Writing Languages in the URLs In the format: (lang).website.com (like wikipedia)

Tags: php

I though that Wikipedia uses a nice way of writing languages in their URLs:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

(where the language precedes the website name)

Is there any way to write the language like this or is it very complex, like a page for every language? I would really love to have this passed as a parameter which I can then use for setting the language of the content.

I've been looking into some httpd stuff which includes AddLanguage like Wikipedia does, but I don't understand how it works or what it does.

I'm not very experienced with httpd nor PHP so there might be a better method of doing this.

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: My guess is that they have multiple versions of each text file sitting in the database and use the subdomain as an additional key to pluck the right one out depending on what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot verify that Wikipedia handles it this way (I suspect it is far more sophisticated there) but for a simple site, you can accomplish this with a wildcard domain in DNS, a simple URL rewrite, and [`gettext()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) or other internationalization method.

Your wildcard domain would be registered as `*.example.com`.  Using a web server that supports URL rewriting, match the first subdomain component, and pass it to PHP as a querystring parameter. Here's an example using Apache mod_rewrite:

```
# Example apache rewrite subdomain to lang parameter:
RewriteEngine On
# Capture the language subdomain in %1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
# And pass the language into PHP as the lang= querystring param
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=%1
```

In PHP, retrieve the language as `$_GET['lang']` and use it to switch languages in your internationalization scheme.

In the case of something like Wikipedia, they are likely to have the same article in multiple language translations stored in their database.  If you are merely translating the strings on your web application, that is done with internationalization functions like `gettext()` or [`intl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)

How you handle the internationalization of your content is entirely up to you.  The important part here is that a wildcard subdomain can be used to switch between languages.

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia uses wildcard domains: https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=operations/apache-config.git;a=blob;f=redirects.conf;h=de2849ecfbbab3c154118e62f4d41bfbad316d7d;hb=refs/heads/master